# How to look though a list of Objects to find a match?

Tags: java, hashset, linkedhashset

I'm trying to compare a bunch of Objects of the same class to search for matching ID's? 
This is the GroupClass, when a new entry is entered it will test against the idNumber to see if there is a match.

```
Public GroupClass {

private int idNumber;
private String name;
private double income;


public GroupClass(int id, String name, double income){
    this.idNumber = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.income = income;
}

public int getIdNumber() {
    return idNumber;
}

public void setIdNumber(int idNumber) {
    this.idNumber = idNumber;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getIncome() {
    return income;
}

public void setIncome(double income) {
    this.income = income;
 }
}
```

This is the Main Method

```
import static java.lang.reflect.Array.set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


    public class ListTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Set<GroupClass> groupArray = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    System.out.println("Enter a ID Number");
    int id = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a First Name");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter a an Income");
    double income = input.nextDouble();


    groupArray.add(new GroupClass(1111, "Billy", 178000));
    groupArray.add(new GroupClass(1112, "Sam", 78000));
    groupArray.add(new GroupClass(1113, "Mark", 79000));

    groupArray.add(new GroupClass(id, name, income));
    printTheClass(groupArray);


}

public static void printTheClass(Set group){
    for(Object theArray: group){
        System.out.println(theArray + " ");
    }
}

}
```

Ive seen a few questions like it but just cant get it to work for my particular case, thanks in advance.

Comment: add hashCode and equals into GroupClass

Comment: if id is unique, perhaps try using `HashMap` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the above comment you override the `equals` method, but this may not be suitable for the long term growth of the class.

But using your existing code try

```
public static void printTheClass(Set<GroupClass> group){
    for(GroupClass theArray: group){
        System.out.println(theArray + " ");
    }
}
```

and

```
public static GroupClass findTheClass(Set<GroupClass> group, int id){
    for(GroupClass obj: group){
        if(obj.getIdNumber == id) return obj;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This can be used as

```
if (findTheClass (groupArray, id) == null) {
  groupArray.add (new GroupClass(id, name, income));
}
```

Comment: also for finding you can use streams: 

`groupArray.stream().filter(gr -> gr.getIdNumber() == id).findFirst().orElse(null)`

Comment: @maxpovver Give me a break, I have just upgraded from JDK1.6 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what is your goal. If you want to reject any new entry if the id already exist, you need to override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of the `GroupClass` so that `LinkedHashSet` knows if two `GroupClass` objects are different:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.idNumber;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof GroupClass && ((GroupClass) obj).getIdNumber() == this.idNumber;
}
```

However, in most cases, you might want to retrieve an entry using its id number. Then it might be better to use a map with id as key, and the GroupoClass object itself as value

```
Map<Integer, GroupClass> groupmap = new HashMap<>()
groupmap.put(id, new GroupClass(id, name, income));
```

and you will have to use `groupmap.keySet()` to iterate the map.

Comment: I have changed it to the HashMap and it worked really well, thanks for that!!